# Probability from a Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, statistics

Is there a way to calculate probabilities given a MGF?  Or, does there exist a method to obtain a probability density function from a MGF?

Here is the problem I am interested in solving:

Find the probability $P(X<1.23)$ given that X has moment generating function $M(t)=(1-p-pe^t)^5$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The moment generating function for a Binomial$(n,p)$ random variable is $M(t) =  (1-p+pe^t)^n$.

Comment: Oh, ok, perfect thanks.